# How to find the amount of random integers/float/zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the specific question:
Write a program using functions to generate a number of random numbers and determine:

1.the number of positive values generated,

2.the number of zero values,

3.the number of negative values generated,

4.the average as a floating point number to one decimal digit

So far i have been able to generate the random numbers and that's about it

```
import random 
def randomNum (x):
    counter = 0
    zerocounter = 0
    while counter <= x:
        t = random.randint(-x,x)
        if t == 0:
           zerocounter = zerocounter + 1
        a = t/x
        print(t)
        average = average + a
        counter = counter + 1
    return average,zerocounter

number = int(input("input max range of numbers "))
average,zerocounter = randomNum(number)
print(average)
print(zerocounter)
```

I have figured out how to count zeros and the average i just need help in  integers and negatives

Comment: Send us your complete assignment; we'll submit it too!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an assignment using `while` loops that the OP doesn't seem to care about.

Comment: I do care about it i finished a set of assignments related to it and i don't how to retrieve these numbers so far i have this:

Comment: You might need to wait for a little while before it's opened.  (But it will be, eventually.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code demo:

```
In [59]: number = int(input("input max range of numbers: "))
    ...: howmany = int(input("how many numbers to generate: ")) #use another variable
    ...: rand_nums=[random.randint(-number, number) for i in range(howmany)]
    ...: #pos_cnt=sum(1 for i in rand_nums if i>0)  #one liner to count the postive ints inside the list.
                                                    #Otherwise use a loop as below
    ...: pos_cnt=neg_cnt=zero_cnt=0 #use 3 separate counters
    ...: for i in rand_nums:
    ...:     if i>0:
    ...:         pos_cnt+=1
    ...:     elif i==0:
    ...:         zero_cnt+=1
    ...:     else:
    ...:         neg_cnt+=1
    ...: print(rand_nums)
    ...: print('there are {} postive ints, {} zeros, {} negative ints'.format(pos_cnt, zero_cnt, neg_cnt))
    ...: print('list mean is:', 1.0*sum(rand_nums)/len(rand_nums))

#sample input & output:
input max range of numbers: 111

how many numbers to generate: 11
[4, -44, -88, 103, 34, 82, 17, 93, 107, -98, 93]
there are 8 postive ints, 0 zeros, 3 negative ints
list mean is: 27.545454545454547
```